# Best authentication method for an API wrapping WP Rest API?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, graphql, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a wrapper around the WordPress Rest API (it will be a subgraph in a federated GraphQL API). I'm wondering what kind of authentication I should use. The WordPress WPGraphQL plugin uses a cookies based auth, I'm not sure how though. My understanding is it is only possible because the plugin is tightly integrated with WP.

Any suggestion is appreciated!